# Image quality issue

Tags: png

I receive 3 Png file but one looks grainy when zoom in but the other looks ok. I check the resolution is the same. So what is the causes of the quality. Although there is different in document size, but when compare a smaller document size with same resolution also looks grainy. Anyone can explain the issue? Thanks.
[image: 84x60 grainy with resolution 72]
[image: 60X40 smooth with resolution 72]
[image: 33x23 grainy with resolution 72]

Answer (score 1):

The "grainy" PNG is in [indexed color mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indexed_color). The reason for this is that the creator of it likely used the "Save For Web" option in Photoshop and saved it as a PNG-8, using fewer than 256 colors.

Depending on the quality you desire, there are a few options you can ask them to do (in order from smallest file size/lowest quality to highest):

- Redo "Save For Web" and increase the number of colors on the PNG-8 to 256
- Redo the "Save For Web" and save as a PNG-24 instead of PNG-8
- Use the regular "Save As" option and select "None" under compression

**I would go with the last option**, as it will provide you with the highest quality PNG.  You can worry about compressing it yourself, after you've done your work with it.